# Strategy to combat new data affecting a "load more" request to a REST API?

Tags: php, ajax, vue.js, rest

I'm building a modern web app (VueJS + REST API). I need to achieve a *'load more'* button and have done a lot of reading. 
I added some query params (`limit` and `offset`) to the endpoint I retrieve the data from. If I want the first 6: `GET /v1/endpoint?limit=6&offset=0`, then when I want the next 6: `GET /v1/endpoint?limit=6&offset=6`, and then: `GET /v1/endpoint?limit=6&offset=12`, and so on. 
The issue I've ran into is: *If there is a new piece of data added after initial load, it will **duplicate** some of the existing data (an equal amount to the amount of data that was added) because it disrupts the `offset`*. 
I'm wondering what the best strategy to combat this would be (without reordering the data so the new data comes last).

Comment: Without knowing what sort of data and the relevance of what order it comes in makes it difficult to suggest a best strategy, also what do you mean by the best strategy?

Comment: List of friends a user has, ordered by number of mutual friends. So imagine Aaron sends a friend request to Ben, and they have loads of mutual friends... If Aaron is visiting Ben's profile page while Ben then accepts the friend request... If Aaron clicks "load more" to see the next six friends Ben has, there is going to be a duplicate user card because Aaron's user card is now at the front because they have many mutual friends and that has pushed Caroline's user card from 6th place to 7th place in the array, making her card load again when the "next 6" are requested. How do I combat this?